# Remove only country code from string not slahsh?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I want to remove only country code not slash from string .

**suppose**: phone number is `+1-555-555-5555` and i want like `555-555-5555`

My code is

```
<?php 
$sPhoneNumber =get_post_meta($post_id, '_vfb_field-23', true);
echo $result = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $sPhoneNumber);
?>
```

it given me output like `15555555555` and i want `555-555-5555`

Comment: Unless you have complete control over the input, you shouldn't assume that phone numbers will be separated by dashes. In many European countries spaces are used, instead. In North America the first part after the country code (the area code) is often wrapped in parentheses. Be cautious about assuming any particular format for phone numbers in user-facing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following regex substitution:

```
$result = preg_replace("/^\+\d+-/", "", $sPhoneNumber);
```

It will remove 1+ digits and a `-` after it from the start of a string.

Using this solution, you will avoid changing strings that do not start with `+` followed with digits.

Instead of `\d+` you may specify the country codes you need to remove. Say, you need to remove `22` and `48` codes:

```
$result = preg_replace("/^\+(?:48|22)-/", "", $sPhoneNumber);
```

Comment: Well, I can also suggest a solution similar to those above: 1) check if the string starts with a `+`, then 2) use `explode` / `substr`. I think a regex - that is quite simple - is good to use in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use substr to get the substring after first '-', **[live demo here](https://eval.in/785514)**.

```
substr($string, strpos($string, '-') + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer : [**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/785522)

```
<?php
$phonenumber = '+1-555-555-555';
$array = explode("-", $phonenumber,2);
echo $array['1'];
?>
```

For more details [**PHP EXPLODE**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use `preg_replace` for it,

```
$result = preg_replace('~^[0\D]++|\D++~', '', $sPhoneNumber);
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/X5Aqm)**

Answer (score 0):

try on this site
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/jXB
this reg

```
[^\+[0-9]-].*
```

using this function

```
preg_match("/[^\+1-].*/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

so basic you gonna find all the is not "+1-"

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, we can use `substr()` function to cut portion of string.

```
<?php
echo substr("+1-555-555-5555",3);
?>
```

Here's a link [PHP substr()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp)